# Cannot resolve symbol 'BitmapRequestBuilder'?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-glide

[I am using below dependency still getting issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ona1L.png)

I am using below dependency still getting issue
`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'`

Issue -
I have done research on stackoverflow and i got some solution like use asBitmap() before the load method still getting below error.

[asBitmap() before the load method (Screenshot Attached) still getting below error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYAy0.png)

Below is my code:

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        BitmapRequestBuilder builder =
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(Constants.IMAGE_DOWNLOAD + pathName)
                        .asBitmap();
        FutureTarget futureTarget = builder.into(width, height);
        return (Bitmap) futureTarget.get();
    }

    private Bitmap loadImageForNoti(Context context, String pathName) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        BitmapRequestBuilder builder =
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(pathName)
                        .asBitmap();
        FutureTarget futureTarget = builder.into(width, height);
        return (Bitmap) futureTarget.get();
    }
```

when i am trying to migrate the glide dependency  from 3.7.0 to 4.13.0
then i am getting above issue so i am confused how to write above function which will work in latest glide dependency  4.13.0.

Comment: Have you added the correct import?

Comment: `BitmapRequestBuilder` isn't present in current glide version (afaik was until 3.8), so "correct import" doesn't exists for 4+... ;) OP should re-write these methods probably using common `RequestBuilder` with some additional chained calls, in fact is asking for help with this task

Comment: yes it's working but it's showing another issue as **into('int,int') is deprecated**  https://ibb.co/t8ck4VS.   one more question is stackoverflow allow to attach image on comments ?